# Camel POJO producing with JAXB data format exception

Tags: jaxb, apache-camel, jaxb2

I am using Camel 2.10.3

Here is my camel context:

```
  <camelContext id="camelContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

    <endpoint id="webserviceStart" uri="direct:webserviceStart"/>

    <dataFormats>
      <jaxb id="jaxb" prettyPrint="true"
        contextPath="com.jaxbtest.package" />
    </dataFormats>

    <route id="myRoute">
      <from ref="webserviceStart" />
      <marshal ref="jaxb" />
      <to uri="spring-ws:http://wshost:8010/service"/>
      <unmarshal ref="jaxb" />
    </route>

  </camelContext>
```

This code works:

```
@Component
public class WebserviceClient
{
    @EndpointInject( ref = "webserviceStart" )
    ProducerTemplate _producer;

    public Response invoke( Request input )
    {
        return ( Response ) _producer.sendBody( input ).getOut().getBody();
    }
}
```

This code (following the "Hiding the Camel APIs from your code using @Produce" section of http://camel.apache.org/pojo-producing.html) does not:

```
@Component
public class WebserviceClient
{
    public static interface MyWebservice
    {
      Response invoke( @Body Request body );
    }

    @EndpointInject( ref = "webserviceStart" )
    MyWebservice _producer;

    public Response invoke( Request input )
    {
        return ( Response ) _producer.invoke( input );
    }
}
```

it throws an exception:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanInvocation nor any of its super class is known to this context.
    at org.apache.camel.converter.jaxb.JaxbDataFormat.marshal(JaxbDataFormat.java:103)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MarshalProcessor.process(MarshalProcessor.java:59)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)
```

If this is a known bug in camel does anyone know the issue that is related to it? Should I create a new JIRA for this? This seems to be such a simple use case of POJO producing.

Answer (score -2):

Generally, when you get this error, it means you haven't set the list of classes on the JAXB context.

You'd do in JAVA DSL -

```
 JAXBContext context =  JAXBContext.newInstance('your classes');
            JaxbDataFormat jaxb = new JaxbDataFormat();
            jaxb.setContext(context);
```

and then use your custom dataformat 'jaxb' as your marshal/unmarshal ref.

Thanks!

Comment: You can see that the contextPath is specified on the `<jaxbDataFormat/>` element. Besides the first example of code works.